# opencv matcher bad alloc + incorrect library dependancies?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I've been trying to match some features on two images using brute force matcher, here's the complete code:

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include<iostream>

int main()
{

    cv::Ptr<IplImage> img  = cvLoadImage("img.jpg",1);
    cv::Ptr<IplImage> img1 = cvLoadImage("img1.jpg",1);

    cv::Mat image(img,false);
    cv::Mat image1(img1,false);

    cv::resize(image,image,cv::Size(image.cols/5,image.rows/7));
    cv::resize(image1,image1,cv::Size(image1.cols/5,image1.rows/7));

    cv::waitKey(0);

    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;
    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints1;

    cv::SurfFeatureDetector surf(20000);

    surf.detect(image,keypoints);
    surf.detect(image1,keypoints1);



    cv::drawKeypoints(image,keypoints,image,cv::Scalar(0,0,255),cv::DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);
    cv::drawKeypoints(image1,keypoints1,image1,cv::Scalar(0,0,255),cv::DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);

    cv::imshow("1",image);
    cv::imshow("2",image1);

    cv::waitKey(0);

    cv::SurfDescriptorExtractor surfDesc;

    cv::Mat descriptors;
    cv::Mat descriptors1;

    surfDesc.compute(image,keypoints,descriptors);
    surfDesc.compute(image1,keypoints1,descriptors1);

    std::cout<<sizeof(unsigned long);

    cv::BruteForceMatcher<cv::L2<float>>matcher;

    std::vector<cv::DMatch>matches;

     matcher.match( descriptors, descriptors1, matches );

     cv::Mat img_matches;
     drawMatches( image, keypoints, image1, keypoints1,matches, img_matches, cv::Scalar::all(-1), cv::Scalar::all(-1),std::vector<char>(), cv::DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );

     imshow( "Matches", img_matches );

    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;

}
```

The program breakes at **matcher.match** with "bad alloc" comunicate, but the problem is the   **keypoints** vector (probably) because it shows that is has 0 size and a couple hundred   milion capacity which is ridicoulus (hence the bad alloc problem). The function   **drawKeypoints** works well, and it draws a sensible set of keypoints on images which look   good in spite of the keypoints vector parameters. I should add that in **Linker->additional  dependancies** I have included libraries names withouth the "d". So for example I have   **opencv_highgui230** instead of **opencv_highgui230d**. This is a neccessity which I wasn't able   to change because if the library names have "d" added, the program quits immediately after start with "the application cannot run succesfully..." comunicate. I have win 7 64, VS 2010, and I'm running the program in debug mode. I would really appreciate some help with the matcher

Answer (score 0):

I did some investigation work and tested your code with **OpenCV 2.3.1** on Linux and also on Windows (with VS2008). Both systems are 32bits.

One important thing to note, is that you are not testing the success of `cvLoadImage()`. If it fails to find the image, you'll get a crash later on:

```
if (!img || !img1)
{
    // log error and quit
    return 1;
}
```

**On Windows the application crashes**. It's important to state that I'm using the exact same code and also the exact same input images:

[image] [image]

The instruction that crashes the application is this call:

```
surf.detect(image,keypoints);
```

The error says:

```
First-chance exception at 0x0038a473 in cv_test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000c8.
Unhandled exception at 0x0038a473 in cv_test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000c8.
```

I'm linking the application with:

```
opencv_core231.lib opencv_highgui231.lib opencv_flann231.lib opencv_imgproc231.lib  opencv_features2d231.lib
```

**It works on Linux** and the resulting image is:

[image]

I don't know what else to tell you. =/

Comment: Thanks a lot, if nothing else I will run it on Linux. In the meantime I'll keep trying:)

Comment: Ok so apparently program works if I use VS with Cmake to rebuild opencv dll-s. Previously I just used the superpack. It is important to note that it only works on release

Comment: Interesting info. I was also using the superpack install.